# automate HDInsight Spark provisioning and submit jobs on Schedule?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, automation, azure-hdinsight

I want to make an automated Spark job submit system/program.
Of course, the system need to provisioning HDInsight first before submit Spark jobs. 
Also, the system submit spark job on schedule base(e.g 7PM submit job1, 9PM submit job2)

What is the best way to acheive those?

c.f) What I can do

- provisioning HDIsinght with Powershell
- Submit Spark job with Livy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like Azure Data Factory would fit your needs. From their website:

"Data Factory allows you to create data-driven workflows to move data between both on-premises and cloud data stores as well as process/transform data using compute services such as Azure HDInsight and Azure Data Lake Analytics. After you create a pipeline that performs the action that you need, you can schedule it to run periodically (hourly, daily, weekly etc.)."

**Resources:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-faq

Comment: Seems like Azure Data Factory fit my need. I will play with DF and then mark your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to run your spark jobs automatically on schedule. So I think using Oozie is very suitable for your current scenario, please refer to Azure offical tutorial for [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-use-oozie) or [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-use-oozie-linux-mac) to know the concept about Oozie. Meanwhile, the tutorial [`Use time-based Oozie coordinator with Hadoop in HDInsight to define workflows and coordinate jobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-use-oozie-coordinator-time) introduces how to do it via time trigger. As reference, a hortonworks thread shows the steps in details for running Spark job from Oozie Workflow on HDP (Azure HDInsight is based on HDP).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah really helpful. I think Oozie is good for spark job scheduling but HDInsight must be created first. Then what is best way to create HDInsight Spark cluster schedule base?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.Net SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-create-linux-clusters-dotnet-sdk) or [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-create-linux-clusters-azure-powershell) to automate the provisioning of the HDInsight instance.

I would use Livy to submit Spark jobs as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-apache-spark-livy-rest-interface)